# How do I prove these gate identities?

Tags: quantum-state, quantum-circuit, random-quantum-circuit

[image]
How do I approach on solving the below two problems?

Comment: Try this article https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9503016. It contains a lot of identities among quantum circuits.

Answer (score 3):

For (a), and in accordance with the hint:

With controls = 00, the target qubit is not operated on (because all the gates have their controls set to 0 and so they do not affect the target).

With controls = 01, the left $V$ and the middle $V'$ are active but cancel each other, resulting in no change to the target.

With controls = 10, the middle $V'$ and right $V$ are active but cancel each other, resulting in no change to the target.

With controls = 11, the left $V$ and the right $V$ are active resulting in operation: $V^2$.

Comment: For controls 01 or 10, I think it should be necessary to specify the qubit ordering